# pointwise mean? pointwise variance?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm currently reading a paper that discusses calculating the Fréchet mean within a function space. The author uses the term pointwise mean and pointwise variance, but I'm unsure of what these refer to. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I'd need a bit more context to be sure what's going on here. Out of context, I would guess that "pointwise mean" means that you have a function $f : X \times \Omega \to Y$ where $Y$ is a Banach space and $\Omega$ is the sample space of some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Then the pointwise mean of $f$ would be $g(x)=E[f(x,\omega)]$. But I'm pretty sure this is not what is meant here.

Comment: Is it similar to regression? I mean, the mean and variance of $Y|x$ are functions of $x$